# create an external install link for a PWA

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, publishing

I have converted my website into a PWA. Right now when the users visit my website they get an install prompt on the browser's search bar on the desktop device and on the mobile device screen, add to home screen prompt appears. What I want is to create an external link for the PWA for the respective devices, which one shared over any messaging system or email will directly let the users install the PWA on their devices. Or, I can create a button on a webpage that on click lets users install the PWA. Please guide me if it is possible by any chance.

Right now, one way that I have figured out is to publish it on the play store or apple store and then share the link. **But I want to upload it to cloud storage like Google Drive/Dropbox, etc. and share the link.**

Comment: To install a PWA the user must be on your HTTPS URL in their chrome browser and explicitly agree to the install prompt shown by the browser. You can add a button to your website to show that prompt when the user clicks on it.

Comment: Hi, Mathias, thanks for your suggestion. Now my question is, How do you create that button?

Comment: Lots of good examples out there. You will need to add a listener for BeforeInstallPrompt. More details here: https://web.dev/customize-install/